# InvalidOperationException when disposing a HttpContent object while being read

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream, task-parallel-library, using

First off I'm using Stephen Toub's `WithCancellation` extension to allow me to abort the `ReadStringAsync` method.  Internally this uses a `TaskCompletionSource` and `Tasks.WhenAny`. Details here; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

The exception gets throw because of the `Using` keyword.  The read is still ongoing when the `End Using` is hit, which disposes the internal stream of the `Response.Content` object.  I understand the read is still running in the background, and I don't mind as long as my code can continue without getting stuck on a long read.

I'm not sure `HttpClient`'s timeout properties apply when doing this kind of read (The request is made with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, so I don't have the content before the read is made).  Also, I may be having an issue where the code gets stuck on the read, due to a bad proxy, so I need to be able to cancel it.

What I don't understand is;

1. Why is the exception not being caught by my try/catch blocks?
2. How can I fix this so I can abort the read and ignore the exception?

Cannot remove the `Using` block because all `HttpReponseMessage` objects are wrapped in `Using`, so when `HttpResponseMessage` is disposed I have the same problem.

```
  Public Async Function GetResponseStringAsync(Response As HttpResponseMessage) As Tasks.Task(Of String)

    Dim TimeoutToken As New CancellationTokenSource
    TimeoutToken.CancelAfter(DefaultTimeout)

    Try

      Using Response.Content
        Try
          Return Await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.WithCancellation(TimeoutToken.Token).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
      End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return Nothing
  End Function
```

This is the output of the `InvalidOperationException` that is thrown.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Can not access a closed Stream.
   at System.Net.GZipWrapperStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

EDIT: After 72 hrs no comments, upvotes or answers.  Is there something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync` does not block. It returns immediately (it's async after all), which triggers the Dispose call on the Content from the finally clause of the using statement, that closes the underlying stream and thus causes the exception.

The stream is already closed by the time the read is attempted. To Dispose the Content after the read you could use a continuation like this:

```
ContinueWith(t => { response.Content.Dispose(); return t.Result; });
```

Hope this helps.